# AWS Elastic Beanstalk and JAVA_OPTS

Tags: java, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a java application which is deployed to Elastic Beanstalk. 
There are two environments: test and production, production is configured to use bigger instances than test.
With the default config for java environment max heap size is around 1/4 of all instance RAM (for 2G RAM instance it's about 0.5G) and I'd like to increase it (`-Xmx`).
Available options are:

- using `.ebextensions` - this way config for both environment will be the same (not good)
- using `Procfile` - the same as above
- using `Environment properties` in console does not work - those properties are passed to application (`-D`), not to `java`.

Any ideas how to set `-Xmx` depending on environment / available memory size?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think of two ways to resolve the issue:

1. two sets of `.ebextensions`, one for `test` and one for `prod`, when you do the app package, just put `.ebextensions` under `webapp` folder, it will be picked up by `Beanstalk`
2. customized `catalina.sh` to `grep` the free memory and adjust the `-Xmx` accordingly.